# How can I made sticky in css which show only on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am using position but it is not working is there any way to get the desired result

position: sticky;

Comment: Please take a look at this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: PS: also read the dexcription of tags you are using. the `web` tag specifically says: *Do not use this tag. For questions related to an aspect of the world wide web, use a more specific tag for it, such as ...*

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  padding: 0 35%;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.
      </p>
      <div>Sticky Div</div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
        esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
        est laborum.
      </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element)

Comment: Please read [answer]. **code only** answers are considered low-quality. Without sufficient explaination it is hard 
to understand what you did or how you solve the issue. As such it is also hard to reproduce and your answer 
is **not helpfull**! A link to an external site is not sufficent to replace an explaination. Answers and questions must always be selfcontaining. Last but not least, you do not answer the question. A sticky element that only is visible during scroll requires JS. Your sticky is always visible.